# supporting 2D arrays in WCF service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I need to pass a 2 D array from VBA (excel) to WCF Service.
WCF service does not support 2D arrays in their Operation Contracts.
Can Anyone suggest some alternative for this 
e-g,

[VBA]

```
ReDim Data(nCol, row) As String
```

This array is a dynamic array in VBA and values are inserted in this. I want to pass this 2D array in a WCF Service .

```
Dim WCFSvcObj As Object
Set WCFSvcObj = GetObject(WcfServiceAddress)
WCFSvcObj.SendData(data, nCol, row)
```

[WCF]

```
[operationContract]
void Senddata(string[,] data, nCol, row)
```

Comment: You can use jagged arrays. See this blog - [WCF Operations and Multidimensional Arrays](http://geekswithblogs.net/JoshReuben/archive/2011/03/16/wcf-operations-and-multidimensional-arrays.aspx) for a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

try using Jagged Arrays

[operationContract]
void Senddata(string[][] data, nCol, row)

It is supported by WCF

Comment: But how can i make Jagged arrays in VBA ? i need to pass the array from VBA